# Requiring multiple Case When conditions to output one THEN

Tags: sql, expression, case-when

I am trying to write a custom expression that states IF x,y, and z are all blank, THEN getdate from a given date to today. This is what I have for now, but i'm not sure if I need a different WHEN/THEN statement for each of the 3 fields, or if there's a way to combine them with an AND or a comma.

```
Case 
 when UnderwritingSuspendedDate is null then datediff(dd,SubmittedToUnderwritingDate,getdate()) 
 when Milestoneapprovedwithconditions is null then datediff(dd,SubmittedToUnderwritingDate,getdate()) 
 when UnderwritingFinalApprovalDate is null then datediff(dd,SubmittedToUnderwritingDate,getdate()) 
END
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

According to your logic, it would be:

```
(case when UnderwritingSuspendedDate is null and 
           Milestoneapprovedwithconditions is null and 
           UnderwritingFinalApprovalDate is null 
      then datediff(day, SubmittedToUnderwritingDate, getdate()) 
 end);
```

Note that if any of the three values is *not* `NULL`, then the expression will return `NULL`.

Comment: Amazing! Much simpler than I was trying to make it. Thank you for your help and quick response